# problem with adding input in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, jquery

why after two click this code adding several input together?

```
$('.add_input').live('click', function () {
            var scntDiv = '.'+$(this).closest('div.find_input').find('div').attr('class');
            var i = $('.adding').size();
            var input = $(scntDiv).clone().wrap("<div>").parent().html();
            alert(scntDiv)
            $(scntDiv + ' .add_input').remove();            
            $(input).appendTo(scntDiv);
            $('<div><a href="" class="remove_input"></a></div>').appendTo('.add_in');
            $(scntDiv + ' .add_in div a:first').remove('')
            i++;
            return false;
        });
```

html: (i use of this html twice)

```
<div class="column find_input">
    <div class="ai_service">
            <div class="column">
                <div class="mediumCell">
                    <input type="text" name="name" style="width: 160px;" placeholder="خدمات دیگر" title="نام پکیج تور خارجی">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column" style="margin: 5px 3px;">
                <div class="mediumCell add_in">
                    <a href="" class="add_input"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you doing i++,  the scope of i is within the handler and I dont see it being used anywhere?

Comment: What do you mean?what do i do?

Comment: what he means is that i = (var), which means i gets declared each time you run the loop, and i++ really isn't doing anything but adding 1 to i every time where it gets declared again. This is unless you have more jQuery you're not showing. This doesn't look like the problem but it's still unclear

Comment: I think we need more information as to what you're trying to do

Comment: .adding is Instead .ai_service, i tell that use of 2 html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm if you're just trying to add an extra input field, your code seems a little overcomplicated for that... Try this?

```
$('a.add_input').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var $wrapper = $this.closest('div.find_input');
    var $input = $wrapper.find('input[name=name]').eq(0).clone();
    $wrapper.children('div').eq(0).append($input);
};
```

I didn't replicate everything from your code, just the cloning/adding new input. If you posted simplified code and my example doesn't apply, I apologize. Also, I **think** you wanted to append your cloned input into div.ai_service?

In terms of why your original code adds multiple inputs, the cloning process you go through probably first clones one input, adds it, clones the whole thing again (2 inputs), adds 2, and so on. You can use $().eq(0) to limit your jQuery object to the first element it finds that matches your selector.

Comment: I think this is what you want, I removed some code from your jsfiddle (didn't seem necessary for your question). Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/539LR/11/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $('a.add_input').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $column = $(this).closest("div.column");
    var input = $column.prev("div.column").clone().wrap("<div />").parent().html();
    $column.before($(input));

});
```

Comment: In which container are you trying to add the new inputs?